# Is there a way to disable .NET browser detection?

Tags: asp.net, browser, .net-2.0

I failed to find a way to disable the browser detection feature added by asp.net 2.0.
I want **all** the request to my page to be treated as if IE is requesting them.
My fix was to add an App_Browsers folder to my project and in it have the following .browser file:

```
<browsers>
  <browser refID="Default">
    <capabilities>
      <capability name="preferredRenderingMime" value="text/html" />
      <capability name="preferredRenderingType" value="html32" />
      <capability name="requiresFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl" value="false" />
    </capabilities>
  </browser>
</browsers>
```

Is there a way to turn this feature off altogether?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the more offensive parts of ASP.Net, imho. No way to just turn it off AFAIK, other than config like this.

You may be interested in [Rob Eberhardt's](http://slingfive.com/pages/code/browserCaps/) pool of resources on the topic.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it is a bit outdated (at least from the "Page last updated: May 19 2005" at the top...)

Comment: oh sure, but so is asp.net 2.0 :)

Comment: Does this mean you CAN disable this feature in version 3.5?

Comment: not afaik, but my 3.X foo is weak - professionally I'm tied to 2.0

Answer (score 1):

You can override the browser detection by setting the [ClientTarget property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3k2ssx2.aspx) on the page to the choice you would like it to make (probably **uplevel** in your case)...

Comment: Thanks, but this will not override the detection - it will just match a different set of configurations...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I was answering this portion of your quiestion: "I want all the request to my page to be treated as if IE is requesting them."