# What might cause Google chrome to not render ASP.Net validators where Firefox does?

Tags: asp.net, firefox, google-chrome, validation

A registration page in a site I'm working on collects information on 2 named contacts, who are **required** to have email addresses and telephone numbers which do not overlap with one another.

I use several **requiredfieldvalidators**, **regularexpressionvalidators**, **CompareValidators** and some **customvalidators**.

**STAGING-> Firefox**: When I view this page using Firefox, all is fine.

**Staging-> Chrome**: When I view it using Chrome anything to do with validators is missing from the HTML source of the rendered page. The javascript and tags pertaining to said validation is completely absent from these pages.

**Local -> Chrome**: All fine again

So what am I doing wrong?

---

**Updates**:

- Staging machine has .Net 3.5 SP1. Local machine has 3.5 SP1 and 4.0
- %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\ **v2.0.50727**\CONFIG\Browsers folder is same on both machines.
- Tried removing browser files from %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\ **v4.0.30319**\Config\Browsers on local dev machine. No effect. Validators still work when referencing local Server

---

**SOLVED:** Full marks to Will because without his help (below) I would have spent hours at this.

Technically the incorrect browser sniffing was down to some rouge browsercaps info in one of the web.configs in the solution. the differences between dev and deploy came about because web.config differs in these scenarios

Comment: Do you have JavaScript enabled in the Staging Chrome?

Comment: I don't think it's anything you are doing; the framework itself makes some determinations about validation support on the client-side...  question: does the validation work server-side?

Comment: @Michael Same version of chrome works locally, but fails against the staging site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps ASP.Net's built-in browser sniffing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3k2ssx2.aspx

Comment: The same instance of Chrome works against the local developer copy of the same site.

Comment: I think Will is on to something, perhaps the browser capabilities data (%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\versionNumber\Config\Browsers) is out of date on the staging server - missing a .NET service pack/update perhaps?

Comment: Entirely possible. You can check by creating a page that dumps out (recursively) the Request.Browser object

Comment: You could also turn off browser detection altogether: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435989/is-there-a-way-to-disable-net-browser-detection

Comment: Ok so the 2 "browsers" folder on these 2 machines appears to be identical.

Comment: However the local machine also has .Net 4.0 & .Net 3.5 SP1 where the staging server has only .Net 3.5 SP1. I tried removing all of the local 4.0 browsers files. This did not seem to alter the local machines capability of using validators under chrome.